# Excel formula is only showing the formula rather than the value within the cell in Office 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've written a formula within an Excel Cell, in Office 2010, and I expect the cell to show its value, but it still shows the formula.  How do I get the cell to show the value rather than the formula?

Comment: Post something you tried and what formula you are trying to implement.

Comment: this will be for all formula in the sheet

Comment: I'm interested to know why this is off-topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if there is whitespace before `=` sign of excel formula

Comment: All of the answers are possible fixes to this particular Excel problem.  But this particular answer turned out to be my solution.  Indeed, there was a whitespace in front of the equal sign.

Answer (score 22):

You might be in formula view:

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to switch

Comment: This keyboard shortcut corresponds to a "Show Formulas" button in the "Formula Auditing" section of the "Formulas" ribbon.

Answer (score 19):

Make sure the format of the cell is set to 'general' not 'text'  (right click on cell and choose format cell)

Formula should look something like this:

```
=1+2
```

Answer (score 5):

Check the formatting (right click on cell, Format Cells). Under tab "Number" the category should be "General". If, for instance, it's "Text" anything typed in would be treated as a string rather than a formula to be interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you include the = sign in addition to passing the arguments to the function.  I.E.

=SUM(A1:A3)  //this would give you the sum of cells A1, A2, and A3.

Answer (score 2):

Add an = at the beginning. That makes it a function rather than an entry.