# Excel does not return cell with initials + date

Tags: excel

I've written my initials and the current date in the cell A11 in sheet ABC which I want to duplicate to some other sheets, but using the formula:

```
=ABC!A11
```

merely returns "=ABC!A11" in the cell I write it into. I recall it working earlier. Anyone have any clue?

EDIT The content of ABC!A11 is:

```
2015-01-07 G.D.
```

Comment: can you add the content of ABC!A11? maybe we'll find some clue over there...

Comment: Thanksf or input! I've edited my original post.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the cell where you have entered the formula is formatted as **text**. Try reformatting that cell or the relevant column/row etc. to **general** format, then re-enter your formula

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried to reload the cell using *general* format, but it did not help unfortunately.

Comment: Another possibility is that you have a space before the = sign - see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120163/excel-formula-is-only-showing-the-formula-rather-than-the-value-within-the-cell

Comment: I reentered the formula. I also wrote the value at another cell in a sheet and referenced to it by writing = and then clicking on where the new value was. This worked when I referenced from one cell, but not when I referenced the same new cell from another.

Comment: @pnuts Hmm that worked, but I have it like that in my current instance as well.

Comment: @pnuts          (I really don't understand the "@username" as it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't so I'm not only doing it to pnuts for the sake of it). 

The problem is that the worksheet is probably 15 sheets big and the cell requires to be updated (manually, then) approx 60 times every other day. But will try that and see if I can gather some more information as to what causes this.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have "Show Formulas" turned on. Go to the "Formulas" tab in the ribbon, look for the "Formula Auditing" section and toggle "Show Formulas."

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I had Show formulas turned off.